# program working in netbeans but when JAR is run it throws ExceptionInInitalizerError

Tags: java, netbeans

When i run my program in Netbeans IDE it works perfectly but when i run it through the JAR file using command prompt it throws ExceptionInInitializerError, what could be the problem with my code?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Seems like you haven't packaged your resources.

Comment: Post your errors in stackoverflow, not in a random link.

Comment: The problem, as the screenshot indicates, is at MainFrame.initComponents(), at line 1818 (gasp!). Paste your stacktraces, and your code, as text, not as images.

Comment: Does the Report Management Project depend on any projects?
Because, it working well in Netbean, so I guess you're missing some configuration, such JVM arguments,....